# Attribute Routing - Include Forward Slash in Parameter Consumed by IRouteConstraint?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting, route-constraint

I'm experimenting with attribute based routing - it's looking great but I have one problem.

I've scoured the docs (attributerouting.net) and SO, but I can't figure out how to use a custom route constraint and pass in a parameter that includes a forward slash. E.g. a URL.

**Attribute on Controller:**

```
    [GET("{url:CustomURLConstraint}")]
    public ActionResult DisplayByURL(string url)
    {
        ...
    }
```

**IRouteConstraint:**

```
public class CustomURLConstraint: IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string urlToTest = values[parameterName].ToString();
        ....test for url here...
    }
}
```

This works great.... except when the URL contains a forward slash, it gives me a 404.

So I added the asterisk to the route parameter, like this:

```
    [GET("{*url:CustomURLConstraint}")]
    public ActionResult DisplayByURL(string url)
    {
        ...
    }
```

But now I cannot access the value in the IRouteConstraint class.

In the CustomURLConstraint's Match method, the value of `values[parameterName]` comes through WITH the catch-all star - as `*url`.

The route values come through with the `action` and `controller` as expected, but with the key `url` as null. There is no `*url` key.